# Which are the optimum cache-related HTTP headers for a content that can change?

Tags: http, caching, cache-control, http-caching, no-cache

We have several files which are served through HTTP and which change from time to time.

Which are the HTTP headers, related to caching, that we should return in the HTTP response to optimize browser load speed while at the same time forcing the browser to validate that it has the last version of the file?

We are already setting an "Expires" header with a date in the past (there seems to be consensus at this point).

But then some people recommend setting this header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

But the problem with this header is that it prevents the browser to keep a local copy of the file, so the file is downloaded every time, even if it doesn't change, with a 200 response code.

If I just use:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Then the browser (at least Firefox 14 and Chrome 20) keeps a local copy, sends `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` headers, and the server returns a 304 code and the file contents are not downloaded.  **This is the optimum behavior for these files that can change at any time.**

The problem is that I don't know if just setting "no-cache" is enough to force all browsers (including old but still used versions) and proxy servers to revalidate their locally cached copy with the server.

Finally, what about `Pragma: no-cache` header?  Should it be included in the HTTP response too?

Comment: If you have an answer, you should write your own answer and mark it as the answer instead of adding a statement in bold in your question.

Comment: @AlexisWilke The bold statement is not the answer to my question, it's just something that I wanted to emphasize.

Answer (score 6):

The Google developers documentation has a [nice documentation on caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) and provides some nice patterns to use.

For instance, it has a flow chart for defining a optimal cache control policy.

[image]

Further, it defines a nice pattern to add a fingerprint to the files and set a expiration for a longer time such as a year.

> - Locally cached responses are used until the resource 'expires'
> - Embedding a file content fingerprint in the URL enables us to force      the client to update to a new version of the response
> - Each application needs to define its own cache hierarchy for optimal     performance

[image]

> The ability to define per-resource caching policies allows us to
>   define “cache hierarchies” that allow us to control not only how long
>   each is cached for, but also how quickly new versions are seen by
>   visitor. For example, let’s analyze the above example:
>
> - The HTML is marked with “no-cache”, which means that the browser will    always revalidate the document on each request and fetch the
>     latest    version if the contents change. Also, within the HTML markup
>     we embed    fingerprints in the URLs for CSS and JavaScript assets: if
>     the    contents of those files change, than the HTML of the page will
>     change    as well and new copy of the HTML response will be
>     downloaded.
> - The CSS is allowed to be cached by browsers and intermediate caches    (e.g. a CDN), and is set to expire in 1 year. Note that we can use
>     the “far future expires” of 1 year safely because we embed the file
>     fingerprint its filename: if the CSS is updated, the URL will change
>     as well.
> - The JavaScript is also set to expire in 1 year, but is marked as    private, perhaps because it contains some private user data that the
>     CDN shouldn’t cache.
> - The image is cached without a version or unique fingerprint and is    set to expire in 1 day.
>
> The combination of ETag, Cache-Control, and unique URLs allows us to
>   deliver the best of all worlds: long-lived expiry times, control over
>   where the response can be cached, and on-demand updates

Comment: There is [another documentation from Google](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#perfect_caching) which is contraditory.  In this document they recommend `Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate` instead of `Cache-Control: no-cache` for content that can change at any time.

Comment: Note that the `ETag` can cause "problems" in Firefox in that it seems to re-check for the data all the time, even if you have a cache duration larger than zero. So files that are versioned, such as the CSS and JS files, should not use `ETag`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, maybe not 100% fitting your needs is:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=315360000, public
Expires:Tue, 23 Aug 2022 10:53:13 GMT
```

And give the file a "content dependent filename" such as stylesheet_v32.css.
As soon as the content changes, change the filename + reference to and the browser gets the latest version. If the filename stays, the browser doesn't need to request it.

This is safe and consistent through out the browsers.

Relying on `Cache-Control: no-cache` and the browsers saving it anyway is what I wouldn't like to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to force a cache re-check by the client:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

This works with at least Firefox. I would imagine that IE and Chrome will also react properly. It should work with older browsers using HTTP/1.0.

With HTTP 1.1, you can use an `ETag`. In that case the `must-revalidate` option is not necessary because having the `ETag` is enough to make the client react as if `must-revalidate` was there:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
ETag: 123
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

This will tell the client to create a cache version of the data with `ETag` 123 and recheck the server every time it needs a copy of that data. You can then reply with a `304 Not Modified`.

The two options that definitively you cannot use are: `no-cache` and `no-store`.

If you want to prevent intermediate caches from caching the data, make sure to add `private` to the `Cache-Control` options.

As an interesting feature, you can also use a small max-age of, for example, a few minutes, to let the client cache the data for that amount of time, then send a `GET` which you can answer with a `304`:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=300
ETag: 123
Expires: Tue, 29 Mar 2015 15:05:00 GMT
```

In this case, the browser is expected to not check for new data for 5 minutes. After that it sends you the `If-None-Match: 123`.